# Minimum of 10 numbers using for loop

Tags: c++

I have a simple question in this code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main () {
int x, mn = 10000;
for (int i = 0 ; i<10 ; i++)
{
     cin>>x;
    if (x<mn)
        mn=x;

}
cout << mn;
return 0;
}
```

Why this outputs the minimum although if cases are true if we consider that the user won't enter a number greater than 10000? 
 
My logic if the inputs are: in example 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10:

```
1<mn 
okay now mn =1; 
2<mn 
okay now mn =2; 
........ and so on, til mn = 10;
```

Why doesn't it output 10 (the last value)? 
 I will be thankful if you help. 

 
PS: I also need a recommendation for better understanding how the code runs to me as a beginner.

Comment: I do not understand what you are asking. Does something in the provided code not work? If so, what isn't working? What do you expect and how does what you observe diffeR?

Comment: It does not output the last value because after the first iteration `mn` would be re-assigned from 10,000 to 1. After that all comparisons would produce a false.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux No, the code runs but I need to understand how this outputs the minimum number? not the last value entered by the user.

Comment: @AdamHussein Which part is confusing you?

Comment: Debugger.  Use a debugger.  A debugger will allow you to single step through your program, watching values of variables.

Comment: because x is placed into mn only if x < mn

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux if statement

Comment: See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if. This is a very basic question that may be better addressed by a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have commented the code to help you understand each line.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main () {       // Start execution
int x, mn = 10000;  // Place a value of 10,000 into minimum - higher than the supposed maximum value that can be entered.  (This is not a good number to use)

for (int i = 0 ; i<10 ; i++)  // Loop 10 times
{
    cin>>x;    // Input a value into x
    if (x<mn)  // if x is less than mn (first loop it is 10,000) then...
        mn=x;  // Assign x into mn.

}
cout << mn;    // Output mn.  If no minimum was entered or found, this prints 10000
return 0;      // return 0
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> Why doesn't it output 10 (the last value)?

Your understanding of the program is not correct.

You said:

```
1<mn 
okay now mn =1;
```

That is correct.

```
2<mn 
okay now mn =2;
```

That is not correct. At this time, value of `mn` is `1`. Hence `2 < mn` is not true. That would be true if you don't change of the value of `mn` but simply print `x`.

```
for (int i = 0 ; i<10 ; i++)
{
    cin>>x;
    if (x<mn)
      cout << x << endl;

}
```

Comment: Thank you, that went so far to my mind, I don't expect that the value gonna change from 10000 to 1. That's what I don't understand.

Comment: @AdamHussein, the line `mn = x;` changes the value of `mn`.

Comment: Got it, he was not able to mentally trace execution the second time through when mn was already equal to 1.  A debugger really helps with this.